# Как узнать версии установленных программ?

Tags: python-3.x

Как узнать версии установленных программ? Т.е на PC установлены программы я получаю список установленных программ и их версию. Для windows. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Что такое по вашему версия?)

Comment: У программ есть версии, например V1.0 , 3.2.7 и т.п.

Comment: Не у всех. И ответ на ваш вопрос - никак в общем случае. В частных случаях - разбиратся с каждым отдельно....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для вывода списка установленных программ в windows можно использовать команду:

```
wmic product get name,version

PS C:\Windows\system32> wmic product get name,version
Name                                    Version
Microsoft DCF MUI (Russian) 2016        16.0.4266.1001
Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016 16.0.4266.1001
Microsoft Visio Professional 2016       16.0.4266.1001
```

В питоне можно получить и распарсить этот список:

```
from subprocess import check_output

check_output("wmic product get name,version")
```

Скрипт должен запускаться от имени администратора

Comment: Это очень неполный список , только то, что устанавливалось Windows Installer (то есть то, что есть в ветке HKCR\Installer\Products). Например, такой распространенный инсталлер как Inno Setup туда ничего не пишет. Это уж не говоря про немалое количество программ, который устанавливаются просто распаковкой из зипа.

Comment: @freim и это единственный "законный")) способ установки программ и возможность его получить. А так, да, в любой ОС можно развернуть архив, не пользуясь никаким пакетным менеджером и запускать программу вручную. А еще можно запускать программы интерпретатором. Но вопрос звучал _"Как узнать версии **установленных** программ"_

Comment: При выполнении скрипта получаю product get name - Alias not found. subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['wmic', 'product get name,version']' re
turned non-zero exit status 44135

Comment: попробуйте не разделяя одной строкой `wmic product get name,version`

Comment: @Dmitry Kozlov, насчет того, что Windows Installer есть единственный законный способ установки программ - давайте считать это шуткой. До такого заявления даже MS не додумалась. Прикиньте, кстати, сколько программ устанавливается альтернативными инсталлерами. MSI далеко в меньшинстве.

Comment: File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 644, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2]

Comment: Смайлик заметили? Угу. Разумеется. Но это единственный "пакетный менеджер" агрегирующий и контролирующий сведения о установленных программах. Остальное - философский вопрос

Comment: И еще: если внимательно посмотреть на выдаваемый список, то можно обнаружить, что наряду с программами там фигурирует масса непонятного мусора. Потому что "Products" это не совсем то, про что спрашивал автор вопроса.

Comment: @AlexFirsov попробуйте не разделяя, одной строкой `wmic product get name,version`. Питона у меня нет, а команду проверял под PowerShell и cmd в Win 10

Comment: Вызвал вот так: subprocess.call("wmic product get name,version") все заработало

Answer (score 0):

В Windows нет способа идентифицировать "установленную программу", что бы под этим ни понималось. Разве что вы хотите найти все .exe на диске.

Что касается версии, то в ресурсах программы может присутствовать запись VERSIONINFO. Но эта запись есть не у всех программ, а если и есть, то нет никакой гарантии, что там действительно реальный номер версии. Программист может поддерживать актуальную версию в диалоге About, а в ресурсах десятый год висит 1.0.0.0